# How can I get the data I need when my function is returning a JavaScript promise object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to access a piece of data through an API and my company gives me a function called `findItemById(id)` that returns a JavaScript promise object. I'm also given a function called `loadPromise("item", findItemById())` that takes a key value in the state object (we're using React.js) and a function and assigns that value to that key in state. I'm trying to use `findItemById(id)` to get the data I need, but I don't want to keep it in state. When I do this:

```
findItemById(id).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I get the exact object I'm looking for in the console. But when I do:

```
const ObjectIWant = findItemById(id).then(function(result) {
    return result;
}, function(err) {
    return err;
});

console.log(ObjectIWant);
```

I get a JavaScript promise object back. If I drill down into the promise in the chrome develper tools, I can see the data I want in there. How can I return the data I'm looking for instead of a promise object?

Comment: Can you please point me to the duplicate question? I've searched for an answer can haven't found anything that helps.

Comment: This is expected behavior for JS; the data in a promise is loaded asynchronously, so it is only accessible in the promise callback. So the callback itself is, indeed, where you have access to the data.

Comment: Also, I think this is the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?noredirect=1&lq=1